# Puppeteer page.click(selector) not responding for IFrames

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, jestjs, puppeteer

```js
await page.evaluate(() => {
  window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);
})
jest.setTimeout(20000)
await page.click('#ApplyBthNAP, #btnCheck');
```

```html
<iframe id="frameContent" frameborder="0" height="100%" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" src="html/status/wlaninfo.asp" style="height: 585px;"></iframe>

<div id="ApplyBthNAP">
  <span class="tabal_head"> 
    <script>
      document.write(status_wlaninfo_language['amp_napinfo_title']);     
    </script>
    Neighboring AP Information
  </span>
  <input style="margin-left:25px;" name="btnCheck" class="submit" id="btnCheck" type="button" value="Query">
  <script>
    document.getElementsByName('btnCheck')[1].value = status_wlaninfo_language['amp_stainfo_query'];
  </script>
</div>
```

The error i keep getting is
 FAIL  test\header.test.js (24.613s)
  × Click and check url (23238ms)

● Click and check url

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null

  at Page.click (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:816:18)
```

console.assert node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:815
    AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: No node found for selector: #ApplyBthNAP, #btnCheck

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total

After a few research i got to know that puppeteer has some bug associated with IFrames. Requirement is to press a button with Value='Query'
The only problem with normal selector method it is showing null. Please enlighten me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean `('#ApplyBthNAP #btnCheck')` instead of `('#ApplyBthNAP, #btnCheck')` to find the button *within* the div, instead of the button *and* the div?

Comment: Getting same error while using ('#ApplyBthNAP #btnCheck')

Comment: Even tried ('#ApplyBthNAP > #btnCheck') as btnCheck is a child id of ApplyBthNAP but its still giving the error

Comment: ● Click and check url

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null

      at Page.click (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:816:18)

  console.assert node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:815
    AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: No node found for selector: #ApplyBthNAP > #btnCheck

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total

Comment: And is the element there on pageload? Do you get the same if you do `Page.waitForSelector('#ApplyBthNAP #btnCheck')`

Comment: The error is different now it can't find the selector. The element appears in case a tab is clicked on the existing page 
Strangely enough that tab button is also result of another button pressed on same page. The Url does not change. Its basically interface of a router.

Comment: The only problem is this that ('#ApplyBthNAP #btnCheck') selector is giving output of
m.fn.init [input#btnCheck.submit, prevObject: m.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "#ApplyBthNAP #btnCheck"]

in console window of browser, it should also act in same session of code as well.